Convergence in distribution but Lindeberg condition fails
Let $(X_n)_{n \ge 1}$ be a sequence of independent random variables with distribution given by
$$ \mathbb{P}(X_n = 0) = \frac{1}{n}, \quad \mathbb{P}(X_n = 2n) = 1-\frac{1}{n}.$$
Check whether the sequence
$$ \frac{X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_n - n(n-1)}{n} $$
converges in distribution.
So everything is prepared to use CLT (the mean of this sum in the nominator is $n(n-1)$ and the variance is of order $n^2$), however I tried to check Lindeberg condition and it fails. Is there any other method I can use?

Are the random variable $X_n$ independent? If yes, write it in your post; then the method is to get the limit distribution is to compute the characteristic functions of the centered averages and prove their convergence towards some continuous function.

Fixed. I tried to work with characteristic functions, but all I get is some terrible product and I have no idea what to do with it.

Let $Y_n=X_n-\mathbb E X_n=X_n-(2n-2)$,  so $Y_n=-(2n-2)$ with probability $1/n$ and $Y_n=2$ with probability $1-1/n$, thus $\mathbb E Y_n=0$.
The MGF of $Y_n$ is
$$
\mathbb E e^{tY_k}=\frac1k e^{-t(2k-2)}+\left(1-\frac1k\right)e ^{2t}
=1+(2k)(1+o(1))t^2-\frac{2^3}{3!}(1+o(1))k^2 t^3+\frac{2^4}{4!}k^3(1+o(1))t^4 -\dots
$$
hence for $k=1,2,\dots,n$ and thus
$$
\log\left( \mathbb E e^{\frac{tY_k}n}\right)=\log\left(1+
\frac1n \sum_{i=2}^\infty \frac{(-2t)^i}{i!}\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{i-1}\right)
=\frac1n \sum_{i=2}^\infty \frac{(-2t)^i}{i!}\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{i-1}+O(n^{-2})
$$
and for
$$
S_n=\frac{X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_n - n(n-1)}{n}=\frac{Y_1 + Y_2 + \ldots + Y_n}{n}
$$
we obtain
$$
\log \left(\mathbb E e^{tS_n}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n
\log\left( \mathbb E e^{\frac{tY_k}n}\right)
=\sum_{i=2}^\infty \frac{(-2t)^i}{i!\times i}+O(n^{-1}).
$$
Hence MGF of $S_n$  converges to
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb E e^{tS_n}=\exp\left(\sum_{i=2}^\infty \frac{(-2t)^i}{i!\times i}\right)
=\frac{e^{2t - \gamma - \mathrm{Ei}(1, 2t)}}{2t}
$$
(which is not normal!)
